# how to add a column that is dropped from dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

i dropped the last column (result) from dataframe to perform one-hot encoding. now i want to add that removed column to predict the accuracy of the model.

i did some research and used "insert", for which the syntax goes like this:
DataFrame.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False)

this is the line of code used to add the removed column.

train = train.insert(6,'amount', int, allow_duplicates=False)

6 - is the position of column
result - is the last column
int - data type of the last column

as far as i know, it should add the column that is dropped earlier. but it does not and do not know what else should i do? also, this is the error which is being displayed:

AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'

i guess, the above error says that the column added is empty and the data type is None. so, could anyone, please help me with how to add/insert the dropped or removed column from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define in series the column values that needs to be included followed by inserting it.
http://pytolearn.csd.auth.gr/b4-pandas/40/moddfcols.html

Comment: thank you for the answer,it made me understand what to do for small data as shown in the example(link you sent) , but what if the data is large , like say it's shape is (640,8), then i cannot define the values for each row in that particular column.

Comment: So, in that case, you can store the values in separate variables before dropping or deleting the columns.